# ssh permission denied when connecting from Kubernetes pod to remote host

Tags: kubernetes, ssh

I'm trying to ssh from a pod into a remote server while specifying an identity file. This fails with the following error:

```
admin@123.123.123.123: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've made sure I can connect from my local host with the same set of public and private keys. It only fails when I try to connect from a bash shell inside the pod's container.
My Job definition is as follows :

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-volumes-population-{{ .Release.Revision }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: populate-volumes
        image: {{ .Values.gitlab.image_repository.repository }}/{{ .Values.phpfpm.image.name }}:{{ .Values.phpfpm.image.version }}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - name: ssh
          containerPort: 22
        args:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - |
            echo "Testing ssh connection..."
            ssh -i/etc/ssh/hetzner_box admin@123.123.123.123
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hetzner-box-identity
          mountPath: /etc/ssh/hetzner_box.pub
          subPath: .pub
        - name: hetzner-box-identity
          mountPath: /etc/ssh/hetzner_box
          subPath: .key
      volumes:
      - name: hetzner-box-identity
        secret:
          secretName: {{ .Release.Name }}-hetzner-box-identity
          defaultMode: 256
          items:
          - key: .pub
            path: .pub
          - key: .key
            path: .key
```

Edit 1:
After further inquiries I've manage to notice that the key pair is passphrase less. I've managed to login using a different key pair, protected by a passphrase. My goal is automation and is therefore unacceptable to have passphrase protected keys. Is there a reason the ssh daemon is refusing to authenticate a passphrase less key?

Comment: The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#secret) note that  "a container using a Secret as a subPath volume mount will not receive Secret updates", so maybe there's a race condition where the secret isn't initially ready so the volume mounts empty? I would debug with `kubectl exec /bin/bash` and cat out the public key to see if it looks right or not.

Comment: @RobertNubel I'm afraid the problem lies elsewhere. I've edited my question to shed more light on my problem. It appears to be tight to the fact that the key is passphraseless.

Comment: Just to confirm. Does the server you are trying to connect to have your public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys`?